# I don't understand clearly why the ideal sources that the value doesn't match can't be connected

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm studying recently *Electric Circuits* (9th edition) by Nilsson. In Chapter 2, an example bothers me.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCPeMz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't understand why these above figures can't be permissible. (I know [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_voltage_law_(KVL)) and [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law_(KCL)), but I want to analyse these circuits with another physical meaning.)

In addition, I want to know what situations will appear in these circuits.

Comment: What "physical meaning" do you expect from `5 = 10`?

Comment: There has to be the assumption that the wires are 'ideal' and have no resistance value that applies here.

Comment: "physical meaning" which I mentioned is what situation will appear in these circuits. For example, which source will explode or which source will be gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such circuits cannot exist in theory because the math does not sum up, as other answers state. However, I think it's worth noting what would happen if you try to build this in practice. The voltage source example would actually become:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjA8c2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's because there is no cable or voltage source in real life with 0 resistance. R1 and R2 would be the combination of the resistance of the cables and the internal resistance of the voltage sources. Their values would probably be very low. The cables would heat up until possibly burning due to the potentially high current.

In parallel (no pun intented), the current source example would become:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHrGiD.png)</sup>

Where R1 and R2 would be the internal resistance of the current sources, and R3 and R4 the resistance of the cables. R1 and R2 would be very high, and R3 and R4 would be very low, so again, the cables would probably heat up and burn.

Comment: I don't think this is true, since the problem lies at an even 'rawer' level. The problem Isn't that there is no load, its that 5 != 10.

Comment: Yeah, that is the theoretical reason for those circuits being wrong. I wanted to give a more practical approach, by explaning why you can't "build" this, because it would actually become something different than you intended.

Comment: James, what Daniel says is true. Just try to put 2 batteries in parallel and see what happens. The ideal circuit however cannot work due to the output impedance of the voltage sources being 0 ohms. Same with the current sources, real current sources always have a very high output impedance, but not infinite!

Comment: @lucas92 thanks for pointing out the internal impedance of the current sources, i've updated the answer to include that example.

Comment: I agree that it would be nice to see more of an explanation as to why the circuit is impossible.  However, when paired with the other answers which cover that question, I like this answer because it approaches the intuitive misunderstanding.  Most likely the OP is thinking "I can connect together any sources I like in real life," and this answer explains why that works but the ideal case does not.

Comment: Note that even with superconductors, the circuit is impossible in real life: any superconductor has a limit to how much current it can carry, and once you exceed that limit, it stops superconducting, possibly with explosive results.

Comment: @Mark if you use superconducting wires, you'll just shift the "bottleneck" to be inside the sources themselves. Even if the sources are made of superconducting wire, the internal structure of a boost converter (for example) limits the amount of charge transferred on each cycle. (In the specific case of a boost converter, the lower voltage one would probably just shut off, leaving the voltage at 10V)

Answer (score 18):

Ask yourself:

For the left circuit, what will be the voltage across V1 ?

- 10 V ? No because V2 puts 5 V directly across V1.
- 5 V ? No because V1 puts 10 V directly across V1.

**Do you spot the contradiction?**

For the right circuit, what will be the current flowing ?

- 5 A ? No because I2 forces 2 A to flow.
- 2 A ? No because I1 forces 5 A to flow.

**Do you spot the contradiction?**

In these circuits **there is no solution** as the sources are ideal so their voltage or current **must** be obeyed (for example: a 5 V voltage source must have 5 V across its terminals).

For the left circuit the KVL states that V1 = V2 as the sources are in parallel, fill that in and you get: 10 = 5

We all know that 10 is not equal to 5.

For the right circuit KCL states that I1 = I2 as the sources are in series, fill that in and you get: 5 = 2

We all know that 5 is not equal to 2.

Comment: The next logical question is, what would happen if we did this in real life?  The answer is our current/voltage sources are non-ideal, so one or both would "break their contract" and not provide the voltage/current specified.  Depending on what type of source it is (chemical, physical, etc), other bad things could happen, like the source permanently breaking, or even exploding.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I'm tempted to say (sarcastically) that you have just re-invented a battery charger :-)

Answer (score 7):

> I don't understand why these above figures can't be permissable.

Because you are literally saying that 10 = 5 in the left figure, and that 5 = 2 in the right figure. Both of which are false and doesn't help you solving the problem at hand.

Circuit theory is using math to solve the equations, if you are going to break math, then you are also going to break the circuit theory and end up with nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

Figure 1 says that there is 10 V between the top and bottom wires at the same time as it is 5 V. This is impossible. With real power supplies (not ideal ones) a very high current would flow and this would be limited by the internal resistance of the power supplies.

Figure 2 says that there is 5 A flowing in the circuit loop at the same time there is 2 A flowing in the loop. This is also impossible. The 5 A supply will increase its output voltage to infinity to try to drive 5 A. In a real PSU the 5 A supply will increase its output voltage to the maximum it can.

Answer (score 0):

## In captivity of dogmas

Talking about such textbook schematics with randomly assigned values ​​without showing the connection to basic circuit applications is as boring as blindly solving a huge number of school assignments.

The OP left EE five years ago firmly convinced that ("ideal") voltage sources should not be connected in parallel and ("ideal") current sources in series since this is bad, incorrect and "not permissible". But if they thought so in the past, such phenomenal circuits as the differential ("long-tailed") pair, dynamic load and CMOS circuits would not have been invented.

Ideal things are impossible, unattainable and create conflict situations as in this case. But by striving for them and closely approaching them we can make unique devices.

## Understanding through experiments

So let's trace the evolution of these two basic "ideal" configurations through fun CircuitLab experiments instead of through edifying explanations. We will do this with both configurations in the following sequence:

- Equalize the corresponding quantities.
- Connect the sources to each other through good but not "ideal" measuring instruments.
- Carefully change one, the other, or both quantities in opposite directions.

## Voltage conflict

### ... between voltage sources...

Following the scenario above, let's connect two 1 V voltage sources to each other. CircuitLab obviously knows that this is unacceptable and warns us with a red circle in the lower right corner that it cannot do a DC simulation.  This is silly because the two voltages are exactly the same, no current is flowing, and each of the voltage sources "sees" an "open circuit".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvvzkJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We can "fool" the simulator in a simple way by inserting an ammeter with very small resistance, e.g. only 1 Ω, into the circuit. To set it, open the ammeter "parameters" window and replace the default 0 Ω with 1 Ω; the CircuitLab is happy and the circle turns green.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6igY8.png)</sup>

Now it is enough to change by only 100 mV V1...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOZ5zd.png)</sup>

... or V2...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR3x3q.png)</sup>

... or both...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWA4Du.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBOzAw.png)</sup>

... and the current significantly changes.

This way we can make an AC "differential amplifier" with current output. Note that V2 has a 180° phase shift.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYmtnj.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 1.7]

### ... voltage stabilizers...

In circuits, we implement this idea not through "real" voltage sources (having power) but through passive non-linear devices having the property of maintaining a constant voltage. We can think of them as a kind of "self-variable" resistors connected in series to the power source. When the output voltage decreases, they decrease their resistance to restore its value, and v.v.

In the schematic below, I have added another but negative voltage source V2 (split supply) to make the circuit diagram symmetric and more beatiful. We can think of the two networks of a voltage source and resistor in series as good voltage sources with dynamic internal resistance. In this conceptual circuit, I have emulated the non-linear resistances by variable ohmic resistors since there are not such constant-voltage non-linear resistors in the CircuitLab library.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgqY0u.png)</sup>

### ... emitter followers

In real circuits, transistors with emitter outputs act as such voltage sources. So, in this arrangement, two emitter followers are connected with their outputs (emitters). They can be thought as two good voltage sources V1+ and V2-.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFsSAy.png)</sup>

## Current conflict

### ... between current sources...

Now, following the scenario above, let's connect two 1 mA current sources to each other. As we have seen, CircuitLab knows that this is unacceptable and, although the two currents are exactly the same, and each of the sources "sees" a short circuit, it warns us with the red circle in the lower right corner that it cannot do a DC simulation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5fD7W.png)</sup>

Now we can "fool" the simulator by connecting a voltmeter with high resistance, e.g. 100 MΩ, in parallel to the current sources (to set it, open the voltmeter "parameters" window and replace the default value with 100 MΩ. The circle turns green.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGbQ0W.png)</sup>

Now it is enough to change by only 100 μA I1...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuurrr.png)</sup>

... or I2...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOyzdQ.png)</sup>

... or both...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHpUOD.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPedeF.png)</sup>

... and the voltage significantly changes.

As above, we can make an AC "differential amplifier" with voltage output. Note that I2 has a 180° phase shift.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2mbSq.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 2.7a]

[image: STEP 2.7b]

### ... current stabilizers...

In circuits, we implement this idea not through "real" current sources (having power) but through passive non-linear devices having the property of maintaining a constant current. They can be considered as a kind of "self-variable" resistors connected in series to the power source. When the output current decreases, they decrease their resistance to restore its value, and v.v.

In the schematic below, we can think of the two networks of a voltage source and resistor in series as good current sources with dynamic internal resistance. As above, I have emulated the non-linear resistances by variable ohmic resistors since there are not such constant-current non-linear resistors in the CircuitLab library.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzBRBG.png)</sup>

### ... common-emitter stages

In real circuits, transistors with collector outputs act as such current sources. So, in this arrangement, two common-emitter stages are connected with their outputs (collectors). They can be thought as two good current sources I1+ and I2-.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUKqQd.png)</sup>